# Is enum addition defined in ANSI C?

Tags: c, enums, undefined-behavior

Is it a guarantee that `state` after this code will be `LX_DONE`?

```
enum lx_state { LX_START, LX_MIDDLE, LX_DONE };

enum lx_state state = LX_START;
++state;
++state;
```

Comment: Sorry for the odd `++` thing…lazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the C standard says, in 6.7.2.2/3,

> Each subsequent enumerator with no =
>   defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression obtained by
>   adding 1 to the value of the previous enumeration constant

Comment: Is the quote from the C99 standard?

Comment: @VilhelmGray not sure where I quoted it from when writing the post, likely C99, but it is identical in C89, C99, and C11 (well, C89 has it in 6.5.2.2)

Answer (score 2):

`enum` is an integer, so yes, `state` *will* be `LX_DONE`, assuming you get rid of the weird double `++`.

Comment: @Ed, I don't see where the UB is, that thing won't compile as it is but his intent is clear enough.

Comment: No, it won't compile, you're correct.  If it did ocmpile it would invoke UB, so I don't see how your answer could ever be correct.  However, as the post has been updated to perform the increment in two separate expressions the question has changed.

Comment: I'll edit the response so that I can remove the downvote.  OP said that the double increment was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

No, but it is guaranteed that the code won't compile.

```
enum lx_state { LX_START, LX_MIDDLE, LX_DONE };

int main() {
    enum lx_state state = LX_START;
    ++(++state);
}
```

gives:

```
e.c: In function 'main':
e.c:6:2: error: lvalue required as increment operand
```